# Tagging and Analysing a Search Query

Tags: search, metadata, nlp, rdf, tagging

I'm developing a search engine which functions taking the semantics of data into account, unlike the usual keyword based index. I managed to develop a reasonable index for the search using **metadata extraction methods and RDF**, but I have **difficulty in using such methods on the search query itself since the search query is very much shorter** that the actual data. any idea how to perform a successful tagging of a search query, using similar methods, natural language processing, etc. ?

Thank You!

Comment: What kind of processing did you do on the documents? The processing on your queries should reflect it to some degree for search to work.

Comment: I used meta data extraction schemes using OpenCalais (http://www.opencalais.com/) web service and used a combined index which has two keyword+rdf sub indexes. But the problem is, these methods fail in analyzing the query since the query is too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sample size of a typical query is too small for semantic analysis to be of any value.

One approach might be to constrain or expand your query using drop-down menus for things like "Named Entities" or "Subject Verb Object" tuples.

Another approach would be to expand simple keywords using rules created from your metadata so that, for example, a query for 'car' might be expanded to the tuple pattern

```
(*,[drive,operate,sell],[car,automobile,vehicle])
```

before submission.

Finally, you might try expanding the query with a non-semantically valuable prefix and/or suffix to get the query size large enough to trigger OpenCalais' recognizer.

Something like 'The user has specified the following terms in her query: one, two, three.'.

And once the results are returned, filter out all results that match only the added prefix/suffix.

Just a few quick thoughts.

Comment: hi, can you please explain more about the first approach you have described, **constraining or expanding the query using drop-down menus for things like "Named Entities" or "Subject Verb Object" tuples**

Thanks!

Comment: Sure. In the case of "Named Entities", you would collect the most popular entities appearing in your corpus into a drop down menu which, when a user selects a value, could be used to constrain or better rank results. So after you receive the query from a user but before you submit it to the search engine, you could add any values from the drop down, formatted as metadata.

Comment: Ok,as I get it, I get the user to specify the tags in the search query, probably using a list of such tags which I have already collected in indexing and use them to get the idea behind the query. Sounds good and simple as well. And I suppose I could get the user to specify some contextual tags as well, so that I can get an idea about the context of the search as well! Cool! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build semantic tree. It will based on the combination of keywords.

For example, automobile -->vehicle --> car this relation technical aspect of car.  travel --

> hire/rent-->vehicle-->car this is something related to travel and rent a car. 
>   In this case [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home?gclid=CJa3mPPYlqkCFYIc6wodwTjXuA) will help you a lot.